# Code to record from microphone and audio devices in asp.net and save on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to record video and audio, from the user's system using asp.net and save on the server.
Is there any simple solution?
I see this link [Code to record from webcam or default video and audio devices in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696484/code-to-record-from-webcam-or-default-video-and-audio-devices-in-asp-net) but this is for Video Recording , i need just voice recording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To record sound from a microphone in a web browser you need to use the [`getUserMedia()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/) JavaScript API. However, this is a somewhat new API that still might change and as far as I know there is no support for this in Internet Explorer and Safari today.

Another option is to use a plugin. Both Silverlight and Flash will allow you to record sound from a microphone but this constrains you to another set of browsers.

Even if you combine both solutions, e.g. use `getUserMedia()` in Chrome, Firefox and Opera and Silverlight in desktop Internet Explorer and Safari you will not be able to record sound on an iPad with Safari.